# Does a Naive Bayesian classifier count distinct occurrences of a word?

Tags: bayesian, classification

I like to use a Naive Bayes Classifier for classifying text. If I have a word which occurs many times in one text, such as *beautiful*, do I count all times or only distinct occurrences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For training Naive Bayes uses distinct words from training texts, but for classifying texts it uses each word occurrence in text for scoring.
Here http://pastebin.com/YtTa2cXm is my implementation of Naive Bayes in java.